# Telegram compilation process:No rule to make target '/usr/lib/libicutu.a'

Tags: c++, compilation

I was following Telegram's compile process at [here](https://github.com/telegramdesktop/tdesktop/blob/master/doc/building-cmake.md) and in the last step when compiling the app itself it gives me this error

```
Built target codegen_numbers__qt_moc
make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/usr/lib/libicutu.a', needed by 'codegen_numbers'.  Stop.
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:456: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/codegen_numbers.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/codegen_numbers.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Are you building on a *nix variant? What does `ls /usr/lib/libicutu.a` give you?

Comment: I didn't got your first question, if your referring to my OS it's Ubuntu 16.04 @StoryTeller

Comment: and there is no libicutu.a in the directory and here's my ls complaining about: ls /usr/lib/libicutu.a
ls: cannot access '/usr/lib/libicutu.a': No such file or directory

Comment: That a *yes* on my first question, it is indeed a unix variant :) So  it's a matter of a missing dependency.

Comment: Well, there's your answer (also present bellow). You have a missing dependency, so naturally you need to install it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install ICU library(static build).

[ProjectPage](http://site.icu-project.org/)

[Build documentation](http://source.icu-project.org/repos/icu/icu/trunk/readme.html#RecBuild)

Comment: and also need to make symbolic link from /usr/local/libicuXXX.a to /usr/lib/libicuXXX.a

Comment: http://download.icu-project.org/files/icu4c/58.1/icu4c-58_1-src.tgz here is source file URL

Comment: thank you, :D it solved the problem but now it's nagging again, any idea?? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40286871/telegram-compilation-process-recipe-for-target-cmakefiles-metalang-dir-all-fa

Comment: and good to mention the correct path where to find the files after installation is `/usr/local/lib/` not `/usr/local/`