# Telegram compilation process: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/MetaLang.dir/all' failed

Tags: c++, compilation, gnu-make

I was following Telegram's compile process at [here](https://github.com/telegramdesktop/tdesktop/blob/master/doc/building-cmake.md) and in the last step when compiling the app itself it gives me [this](http://paste.ubuntu.com/23388320/) error, to be brief the error's final lines are:

```
CMakeFiles/MetaLang.dir/build.make:189: recipe for target 'MetaLang' failed
make[2]: *** [MetaLang] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:721: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/MetaLang.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/MetaLang.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

P.S. my OS is Ubuntu 16.04 and the folder in which the process is going on is `~/Documents/Telegram/`

Comment: Did you install `libicu-dev`? It seems, that CMake cannot find ICU libraries. And if you have installed them, which version do you have?