# ICU library build error (telegram-desktop for debian-jessie)

Tags: c++, raspbian, telegram, icu, raspberry-pi3

I'm trying to build telegram-desktop on RPi 3 (debian-jessie) following [this](https://github.com/telegramdesktop/tdesktop/blob/master/doc/building-cmake.md) guide. I encuntered [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40239164/telegram-compilation-processno-rule-to-make-target-usr-lib-libicutu-a/40387370#40387370) error involving ICU library, so that I've done the following steps:

1. downloaded ICU 58.1 sorce file
2. decompressed in `~/` and configured with `./configure`
3. commented out the LDFLAGSICUDT flag in `~/icu/source/config/mh-linux` as described in another StackOverflow question
4. `sudo make` and `make check` (fine)
5. `sudo make install`

At this point it is prescribed in the above answer "to make a symbolic link  from /usr/local/libicuXXX.a to /usr/lib/libicuXXX.a". I guess I have to run

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/libicutu.a /usr/lib/libicutu.a
```

(it's right?) but the problem is that I can't find `/usr/local/lib/libicutu.a`!

Comment: [This](http://download.icu-project.org/files/icu4c/58.1/icu4c-58_1-src.tgz) is hte ICU library source that I've downloaded . 
[This](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=50181&p=392071) is the question that I mention in point 4.

Comment: I've found this file in `/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf`, but I don't know if it is the right file and if it was created compiling ICU 58.